# plot with overlapping points

Tags: r, plot

I have data in R with overlapping points.

```
x = c(4,4,4,7,3,7,3,8,6,8,9,1,1,1,8)
y = c(5,5,5,2,1,2,5,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,2)
plot(x,y)
```

How can I plot these points so that the points that are overlapped are proportionally larger than the points that are not. For example, if 3 points lie at (4,5), then the dot at position (4,5) should be three times as large as a dot with only one point.

Comment: in addition to all of these answers, there is a `sizeplot` function in the `plotrix` package ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simpler (I think) solution:

```
x <- c(4,4,4,7,3,7,3,8,6,8,9,1,1,1,8)
y <- c(5,5,5,2,1,2,5,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,2)
size <- sapply(1:length(x), function(i) { sum(x==x[i] & y==y[i]) })
plot(x,y, cex=size)
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's one way using `ggplot2`:

```
x = c(4,4,4,7,3,7,3,8,6,8,9,1,1,1,8)
y = c(5,5,5,2,1,2,5,2,2,2,3,5,5,5,2)
df <- data.frame(x = x,y = y)
ggplot(data = df,aes(x = x,y = y)) + stat_sum()
```

[image]

By default, `stat_sum` uses the proportion of instances. You can use raw counts instead by doing something like:

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(x = x,y = y)) + stat_sum(aes(size = ..n..))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
## Tabulate the number of occurrences of each cooordinate
df <- data.frame(x, y)
df2 <- cbind(unique(df), value = with(df, tapply(x, paste(x,y), length)))

## Use cex to set point size to some function of coordinate count
## (By using sqrt(value), the _area_ of each point will be proportional
##  to the number of observations it represents)
plot(y ~ x, cex = sqrt(value), data = df2, pch = 16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You didn't really ask for this approach but alpha may be another way to address this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=x, y=y), aes(x, y)) + geom_point(alpha=.3, size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the parameter `cex` to your plot function. First what I would do is use the function `as.data.frame` and `table` to reduce your data to unique (x,y) pairs and their frequencies:

```
new.data = as.data.frame(table(x,y))
new.data = new.data[new.data$Freq != 0,] # Remove points with zero frequency
```

The only downside to this is that it converts numeric data to factors. So convert back to numeric, and plot!

```
plot(as.numeric(new.data$x), as.numeric(new.data$y), cex = as.numeric(new.data$Freq))
```

Comment: Great. `as.data.frame(table(x,y))` is the simple aggregation function I was looking for.

Comment: Important edit: table(x,y) converts numeric data to factors, so you need to convert them back to numeric data when you plot. Just realized this myself!

Comment: In fact you'll have to be even more careful than that, using `as.numeric(as.character(x))` or (to pre-emptively take care of the `as.character()` bit, do `as.data.frame(table(x,y), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`). Also, no need to wrap `new.data$Freq` in `as.numeric()`, since it's already an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to try `sunflowerplot`.

```
sunflowerplot(x,y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose alternatives to adjusting the size of the points.  One of the drawbacks of using size (radius?  area?) is that the reader's evaluation of spot size vs. the underlying numeric value is subjective.

So, option 1:  plot each point with transparency --- ninja'd by Tyler!
option 2: use `jitter` to push your data around slightly so the plotted points don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `lattice` and `table` ( similar to @R_User but no need to remove 0 since lattice do the job)

```
   dt <-  as.data.frame(table(x,y))
   xyplot(dt$y~dt$x, cex = dt$Freq^2, col =dt$Freq)
```

[image]